# Javascript - locating a specific index in an array

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript and your help would be much appreciated.

```
germany
france
uk
italy
spain
poland
romania
netherlands
belgium
greece


clickData.points[0].label
//germany [console: tells what country was clicked on - as shown in the image]

var iExpandPos = clickData.points[0].fullData.labels.indexOf(clickData.points[0].label)
//2 [console: tells the index position of the country]

var len = clickData.points[0].fullData.labels.length;
//10 [console: gives the total number of countries listed]
```

**What i want to do is:**

If a country is clicked [example germany] make the `pull = 0.2` and the
pull for the rest of the countries should be `pull = 0.1` but i am unsure how to write this code as my below code keeps breaking. Your advise would be veryhelpful.

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById(chartDivID);
console.log('myPlot:------------>', myPlot.data[0])
clickData = data;
var iExpandPos = clickData.points[0].fullData.labels.indexOf(clickData.points[0].label)
var len = clickData.points[0].fullData.labels.length;
var pts = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.points.length; i++) {
    pts = 'country= ' + clickData.points[0].label + '\nvalue = ' + clickData.points[0].value + '\nposition = ' + iExpandPos;


    int[] pull = new int[](len);
    for (i = 0; i = len) {
        if (i === iExpandPos) {
            pull[i] = 0.2
        }
        else {
            pull[i] = 0.1
        }
    }

    console.log('check:------->', pts)
}
```

[image]

Comment: `for (i = 0; to len) {` Is your first issue. I never heard of `to` keyword in a for loop. Check your console and post what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that second for loop and the way you create the array `pull` is wrong. Here is a correction of your code :

```
var myPlot = document.getElementById(chartDivID);
console.log('myPlot:------------>', myPlot.data[0]);
clickData = data;
var iExpandPos = clickData.points[0].fullData.labels.indexOf(clickData.points[0].label);
var len = clickData.points[0].fullData.labels.length;
var pts = "";
var pull = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.points.length; i++) {
  pts = 'country= ' + clickData.points[i].label + '\nvalue = ' + clickData.points[i].value + '\nposition = ' + iExpandPos;

  var val = i === iExpandPos ? 0.2 : 0.1;
  pull.push(val);

  console.log('check:------->', pts);
}
```